# How will they mitigate the effect microgravity has in the BFR on manned trip to mars?

Tags: spacex, crewed-spaceflight, microgravity, spacex-starship

Very curious to know this, since it doesn't look like the BFR will utilize centrifugal force to emulate gravity as far as I know.

Comment: I think, in general, the strategy for mitigating the effects of the trip is to keep it as short as possible, around three months. If you keep yourself in decent shape with resistance machines aboard the ship, I would think that you'd be able to handle .38g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make trips that carry humans as short as possible.
2. Frequent physical resistance exercise, as on the ISS.
3. Build extra muscle mass and strength before departure, to help counter losses during the trip.

Perhaps mission planners will also look into the idea of putting a slight spin on the BFS while in transit. I haven't seen any reports of that yet, though.

IMO, it's likely that the low-gravity environment on Mars will also have an adverse effect on human health in the long term, without focused efforts to counter it.

Comment: Spin on a compact spacecraft like BFS won't give significant gravity without severely nauseating inner-ear effects.

Comment: For rotation around the long axis of the BFS, yes. However, rotation around the short axis (end-over-end) may also be an option. Whether that would help enough at low enough speeds to avoid inner-ear problems to be worth the engineering headaches involved, I don't know.

Comment: The BFR is large enough for a Skylab-style ring track to work: running in circles against the inner hull is enough to create some personal spin gravity - enough to actually run against the wall without restraints, and maybe enough to help mitigate some of the effects of microgravity.